# Modified vendor application for Yii2 in GitHub

Tags: php, github, composer-php, yii2, packagist

I have very little experience with creating a vendor application and installing with composer. It worked well for a simple plugin. 
I have a problem with a larger plugin. I got the GII code generator of yiisoft/yii2-gii and modified it to do advanced stuff. I added it to 
https://github.com/harlangray/yii2-gii-advanced

Then changed these

```
"name": "harlangray/yii2-gii-advanced"

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "harlangray\\gii\\": ""
    }
```

But I cannot install it using `"harlangray/yii2-gii-advanced": "*"`
in either `require` or `require-dev` sections. 
I have added it to packagist too. What am I missing here? I'm new to composer and stuff. Only have experience with one little plugin. Thank you.

Comment: Hi it worked when I added "kartik-v/yii2-builder": "dev-master". I thought "*" should get me what ever version there is. I still don't know the logic behind it. Thanks for your rely.